# Creating PHP CLASS for USERS

Tags: php, class, methods, constructor

So, here is my problem and I would very much appreciate any help. I have this assignment:
Create class User with this properties: id, first_name, last_name, age.
Class must have: 1) Constructor, 2)Method that returns fname and lname, and 3) Method that returns boolean if user is underaged or not. Then, create an Object as instance for created class, and through object call both methods and show result on page.

This is what I created so far, but I think I am not going in the right direciton:

```
<?php

class UsersClass {

    public $user_id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $age;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
    }

    public function notUnderaged ($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
        if($age<18) {
            $ageOK = false;
        }else{
            $ageOK = true;
        }
        echo $ageOK;
    }

    public function dataOutput ($first_name, $last_name) {

        echo "First name: " . $this->first_name . "<br/>Last name: " . $this->last_name;

    }

}

$user = new UsersClass;
$user->dataOutput($first_name, $last_name);
$user->user_id = 0001;
$user->first_name = "Vladimir";
$user->last_name = "Bozic";
$user->age = 17;
```

?>

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Your constructor implementation is wrong, you need specify any input paremeters if you want to setup and its like a homework. This site is not for that. Check any tutorial or documentation how works objects in PHP. Thank you

Comment: Are you aware that you are not actually asking a question? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are some issues.

1. Your constructor should be parameterised

   `public function __construct ($user_id, $first_name,$last_name) {
       $this->user_id = $user_id;
       $this->first_name = $first_name;
       $this->last_name = $last_name;
   }`
2. Method that returns first name and last name. You should have methods that return last name and first name. `public function getLastName() { return $this->last_name;}`. Similarly for first name.
3. `notUnderaged` method should `return $ageOk` and not `echo $ageOk`
4. Lastly, all your variables should be private. Since your question doesn't state them to be public.
5. Your method `dataOutput()` isn't required.

So, you'll be calling it like

```
$user = new UserClass(001,'Vladmir','Bozic');
$lastName = $user->getLastName();
$firstName = $user->getFirstName();
```

and so on..

P.S: Tips - It's preferred class methods have getter and setter methods. It provides transparency and visibility of your class implementation. Any operation regarding fetching a value from a variable or performing some operation should be done either via the getter/setter methods or methods derived from getter and setter methods.

Comment: @daremachine  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @daremachine i think it's a fair question

Comment: @daremachine Sory, mate, but everywhere I go, everyone points me to this place for help... This maybe is not a payed project, but is a project, and I tried my best with the knowledge I have to do this. I never wanted for someone to do whole assignment for me, I needed some guidelines, and I asked my question like that. One more time, I am sorry, will try different approach next time, and thanks for your time of course...

Comment: @Tharos hi, please don't refrain from posting questions. These types of questions are more than welcome if they are complete in nature ;)

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay No no, missunderstanding. In question I don't see qustion about "i had error" " what best approach is" etc. I saw only just "I need to do following", I am glad to help someone who want to help with problems. Its fair to   do code review. And your link "Never use code you don't understand". I saw that. I am sorry and Theros dont stop asking and learn more and more to be best ;)